# Can these sets meet? 2

Tags: general-topology

While solving a problem and after applying the Baire category theorem, I arrived to an obstacle. My problem can be simplified and formulated as follows: Suppose $(F_{n})$ is an increasing sequence of closed sets, $B$ is an open ball, all in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. Set $A:=\cap_{n}\partial F_{n} $ and suppose $A$ has  no isolated points. If the boundary of $B$ is entirely included in $A$, can we conclude that $B\cap A$ is empty?

Comment: What if $F_n=\overline{B_1(0)}\setminus B_{1/2}(0)$?

Comment: You mean 1/n...

Comment: My edit was for a typo only (closed sets, not closed set).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $$\partial B\subsetneqq F=\bar F =\partial F \subset \bar B $$  and F has no isolated points. Since $F=\bar F=\partial F$, the open set $B$ \ $F$ is dense in $B$, so let $$F_n=F\cup \{p_j:1\leq j< n\}$$ where $\{p_j: j\in \mathbb N\}\subset B$ \ $F.$

Then $F_{n+1}\supsetneqq F_n=\bar F_n$ and $\partial F_n= F_n.$  And $A\cap B=F\cap B =F$ \ $\partial B \ne \phi.$

To construct such an $F$, let $S$ be a Cantor-like subset of $[-1,1]$. That is, S is a non-empty  closed nowhere-dense subset of $[-1,1]$ and $S$ has no isolated points. If $k=1$ let $T=S.$ If $k>1$ let $T=S\times \{0\}^{k-1}.$ Let $B=B(0,1)$ be the open ball of radius $1$ in $\mathbb R^k$ centered at the origin. Finally let $F=T\cup \partial B.$

Answer (score 1):

No.  Let F_0 be a closed ball, F_n = F_0 cup some closed 
set disjoint from F_0 and larger than the previous one 
and B = int F_0.  The boundary of B = A.  A has isolated 
points only in the one dimensional case.